# How do I get a value from a object when it's one string?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
"{"OrderId":XXXXXX,"IsPrebuy":true,"IsReserve":false,"Date":"2019-11-19","ReservationFee":0,"MovieTitle":"Joker"}"
```

This is the value in an input-tag after a purchase. How do I get the value of "MovieTitle"? 
as you can see everything is within " ".

When I tried this:

```
var products = "{"OrderId":XXXXXX,"IsPrebuy":true,"IsReserve":false,"Date":"2019-11-19","ReservationFee":0,"MovieTitle":"Joker"}"
```

and then i tried this:

```
    (Object.values(products))
(556) ["{", """, "O", "r", "d", "e", "r", "I", "d", """, ":", "9", "9", "3", "9", "1", "1", ",", """, "I", "s", "P", "r", "e", "b", "u", "y", """, ":", "t", "r", "u", "e", ",", """, "I", "s", "R", "e", "s", "e", "r", "v", "e", """, ":", "f", "a", "l", "s", "e", ",", """, "D", "a", "t", "e", """, ":", """, "2", "0", "1", "9", "-", "1", "1", "-", "1", "9", """, ",", """, "R", "e", "s", "e", "r", "v", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "F", "e", "e", """, ":", "0", ",", """, "M", "o", "v", "i", "e", "T", "i", "t", …]
```

I don't know what the next step would be?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the form of JSON. Therefore, parse the string into an JSON object.

```
var products = JSON.parse('{"OrderId":"XXXXXX","IsPrebuy":true,"IsReserve":false,"Date":"2019-11-19","ReservationFee":0,"MovieTitle":"Joker"}')
```

Then get the movieTitle value from JSON object,

```
products.MovieTitle;
```

**Note:** If your order id's type is string, then you have to surround it with double quotes.